# Sending Push Notification Keeps Waiting on a Web Panel

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I have a Web Panel on Genexus X Ev2 U7 where I´m trying to send a push notification to my Android app developerd on Genexus X Ev3 U5.

The code is the following:

Event Start

```
&MessageCharacter = 'Mi Notificacion'
&GpsDeviceToken = 'APx91bFWDR86o4sx7DeP2mmqLaO5RIRp1g_giDFu2grYIpDQxY5Nw3F_AcYERmAkQLjqzVcXtY9tveUYOemUztFzH8DVfeWefIhxmsNMkPHDFjP44cao_ch97PMmianhdpahQtQANPubc70FsKUpFJqrSNZcGVurEQ'
&GpsDeviceType = SmartDeviceType.Android
```

EndEvent

Event Enter

```
&RemoteNotification = new()
&RemoteNotification.DeviceToken = &GpsDeviceToken
&RemoteNotification.DeviceType = &GpsDeviceType
&RemoteNotification.Message = &MessageCharacter
//&RemoteNotification. .Event.Name = &EventNameCharacter


 //Send
 &Notifications.OpenSession("EncuestasMoviles")
 &Notifications.Add(&remoteNotification)
 &Notifications.Send()
```

EndEvent

When I execute enter event, web page keeps waiting.

Is this the correct way to send notifications?

Regards,
Rogelio Arosemena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in Genexus Ev2, sending method is different. The code that works is:

```
&Notifications.Call(&SdAplicationMainPanelName,&DeviceType,&DeviceToken,&MessageCharacter)
```